# Is "Every set can be well ordered" and $(\forall x \in V)(\exists y \in On)(f \in V)[f: x \leftrightarrow y]$ equivalent

Tags: set-theory

From Ex 2.4.4 of Devlin's 1993 textbook,The Joy of Sets: Fundamentals of Contemporary Set Theory.

Are the statements "Every set can be well ordered" and $(\forall x \in V)(\exists y \in On)(f \in V)[f: x \leftrightarrow y]$ equivalent where V is the collection of all sets and $On$ be the class of all ordinals.

I'm not sure if I'm going in the  right direction but basically the second statement is saying there exists a particular ordinal for every set (V is the collection of all sets). To be well founded however, there needs to be a minimal element in each subset. I'm not sure what the $f$ means in this context in applying it to show equivalency. Any help would be good.

Comment: Your statement seems to mix a lot of notation. Is there a reason not to just write it in English, rather than using dubious symbols (ZF doesn't allow for membership in classes, for example, and $f:x\iff y$ means nothing in any version of set theory I know.

Comment: I mean, it appears you are asking if it is true that: a set can be well-ordered if and only if there is a bijection between $x$ and an ordinal.

Comment: Use `\leftrightarrow` to get $\leftrightarrow$; `iff`, which gives $\iff$, means "if and only if", and it is a semantic symbol.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are asking to prove: A set can be well ordered iff it is in bijection with some ordinal. The backward direction of this is trivially true. For the forward direction use transfinite induction to prove that if no ordinal is isomorphic to the set, then every single ordinal is isomorphic to some initial segment, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The $ f $ is a bijection; $ f : x \Longleftrightarrow y $ means that $ f $ is a bijection from $ x $ to $ y $ (a one-to-one function with domain $ x $ and range $ y $).  Or at least it had better mean that; you might want to check where this notation is introduced in the book, because it's not entirely standard.  But if it means that, then the statement is correct.

The equivalence between the two statements depends on the fact, which hopefully has already been established, that every well-ordered set is isomorphic to a particular ordinal.  That is, for each set $ x \in V $, for each well-ordering $ \prec $ on $ x $, there is a (unique) ordinal $ y \in O n $ and a (unique) bijection $ f : x \Longleftrightarrow y $ that preserves and reflects the ordering relations on $ x $ and $ y $.  (That is, for each $ a , b \in x $, $ a \prec b $ if and only if $ f ( a ) < f ( b ) $, where $ < $ is the standard order relation on the ordinal $ y $.  If ordinals are defined in the usual way, due to von Neumann, then $ < $ will be the set-membership relation $ \in $, so $ a \prec b $ iff $ f ( a ) \in f ( b ) $.  Except that this book might prefer to use $ \preceq $ and $ \leq $ instead of $ \prec $ and $ < $, and then you get $ a \preceq b $ iff $ f ( a ) \in f ( b ) $ or $ f ( a ) = f ( b ) $.  Hopefully one of these ways of putting it looks familiar.)  If this has *not* already been established, then Shinrin-Yoku's answer has a hint for how to prove this; but I would expect this to have been covered before asking this exercise.

So ‘Every set can be well-ordered’ is equivalent to ‘Every set can be made isomorphic to some ordinal’, assuming that ‘Every well-orderd set is isomorphic to some ordinal’ has already been proved.  And ‘Every set can be made isomorphic to some ordinal’ is immediately equivalent to ‘Every set is bijective to some ordinal’, because you can always pull back the order relation from the ordinal to the set (that is, define $ a \prec b $ in $ x $ to mean that $ f ( a ) < f ( b ) $ in $ y $).